# Триггер с изменением вставляемых в значений

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо при добавлении записи в таблицу, рассчитать последний столбец.

Например, если вставляется

> (ID | UserName | CreatedTime | AsText)

то вставляемое значение установить

```
DECLARE @new_str = 'Новое сообщение: ' + UserName + ', создано: '+CreatedTime;

AsText = @new_str
```

Остальные значение оставить прежними. Может есть пример! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER SomeTrigger ON SomeTable
AFTER INSERT AS
DECLARE @new_str nvarchar(32);
SET @new_str = 'Новое сообщение: '+ (SELECT UserName FROM inserted) + ', создано: '+(SELECT CreatedTime FROM inserted);

    UPDATE SomeTable
    SET AsText = @new_str
    FROM inserted
    WHERE SomeTable.Id = inserted.Id;
```

Comment: Может будут замечания.

Comment: + (SELECT UserName FROM inserted) +  вызовет ошибку при вставке нескольких записей. проще будет на мой взгляд

UPDATE SomeTable 
    SET AsText = LEFT('Новое сообщение: '+SUSER_SNAME()+', создано: '+CAST(GETDATE() AS VARCHAR, 32)    FROM inserted 
    WHERE SomeTable.Id = inserted.Id;

Comment: ага, пропустил закрывающую скобку у CAST

Comment: Да, действительно, это меня как раз и смущало, _inserted_ возвращает коллекцию вставляемых значений, Вы правы.
Просто первый вариант меня тоже бы устроил, так как вставка нескольких значений не должна быть возможна. Но это неверный подход для установки ограничений. Спасибо.